# Validating contact form in PHP

Tags: php, html, validation, contact-form

I have a contact form which I need validating in PHP to check if each field is correctly filled.

Here is what I have:

```
//Post fields
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_services = $_POST['services'];
$field_it = $_POST['it'];
$field_location = $_POST['location'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];


//mail_to omitted 


//Validation of contact form

$errormessage = '';
if($field_name == ''){

$errormessage += 'You have not entered your Name\n';
}

if($field_email == ''){

$errormessage += 'You have not entered your Email Address\n';
}

if($field_services == ''){

$errormessage += 'You have not chosen the service you require\n';
}

if($field_it == ''){

$errormessage += 'You have not chosen the Date of your event\n';
}

if($field_location == ''){

$errormessage += 'You have not entered the location of your event\n';
}


if($errormessage != ''){ ?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('The following fields have not neen entered correctly\n<?php echo "$errormessage" ?>');
    window.location = 'contact.html';
</script>
<?php } 



if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'contact.html';
</script>
<?php
}


else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to s_ejaz@live.co.uk');
    window.location = 'contact.html';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

This does nothing when I try to submit an empty contact form, it should alert the user of the particular fields which were not filled but it doesn't. It just takes me to a blank white page.

Could anyone help me find where I am going wrong?

Comment: for a start your sending the mail before any validation

Comment: blank white page? What does your error log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `strlen()` and `isset()` to check if any data was received from the form.

Example:

```
if(!isset($_POST['name']) || strlen($_POST['name']) < 1){
    $errormessage .= 'You have not entered your Name\n';
}
```

Comment: No, I changed it to `.=` as you said.

Comment: you should not validate this answer , cause it lead other persons to do same mistake

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use trim function to delete any space.

```
trim($_POST['name'])...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing variable to empty string like this `$field_services == ''` , use [empty()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or [isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

`if(!empty($field_services))` or `if(isset($field_services))`

An other problem is that you concatenate strings using `+` , this is true if you are using `javascript` ,`java` or `C#` etc.. not `PHP`.

To concatenate variables using PHP:

```
 $var='Hello';
 $var.=' World !'

 echo $var;// Hello World !
```

**So your code should be :**

```
 if(empty($_POST['name'])){
   $errormessage .= 'You have not entered your Name\n';
}
```

Comment: Yeah :p too used to JavaScript... `.=` it is

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$errormessage.='Some text\n';` instead of `$errormessage+='Some text\n';`.
Using "`+`" instead of "`.`", PHP treats the variable `$errormessage`as a number, and the assertion failed.